# Defining zsh aliases and functions systemwide

Tags: zsh, path, alias

What's the most efficient way to export the functions/aliases defined in my .zshrc to be used anywhere. For example in my .zshrc

```
_foo() {
echo "bar"
}
```

And then invoke _foo in any script.

Comment: does `zsh` follow the convention `bash` uses, whereby you could have a global `rc` file such as `/etc/zshrc`?

Comment: That or you could setup a script in /etc/profile.d that should be sourced no matter what shell you run.

Comment: The table of zsh dotfiles at this link may help: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-2-configuration-files/.  It looks like `/etc/zshenv` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, you *could* put them in the file `/etc/zshenv`. **However,** on many distributions, this file is supplied by the OS. Besides that, `/etc/zshenv` is sourced *every time* your system runs a Zsh script, even when it's not from an interactive shell. Putting too many customizations in `/etc/zshenv` has the potential to significantly slow down your system or even break things.

Instead, if your custom functions and aliases are meant for interactive usage only, it is generally wiser to **put them into `/etc/zshrc`,** which is sourced only for *interactive* shells.

Documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files