# /etc/zshrc is not applied when log in

Tags: shell-script, zsh, alias

I have no idea why having aliases that are applied to all interactive terminal (i.e., my user account and sudo) is so difficult. Most web search result were about BASH, but my shell is ZSH (Manjaro Linux), so /etc/bash.bashrc did not work.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639554/379327) says that I should put it in /etc/zshrc, but it seems that that file is not applied when log in, unless I manually run `source /etc/zshrc`. Why isn't it applied when log in (user ssh, or sudo for that user)?

PS: I have also tried /etc/zshrc, /etc/zshenv, /etc/zprofile, as [this page said](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e). None of them were applied when log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the system files depends on the operating system. `/etc/zshrc` and friends (as listed in the [online documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files)) is the default, but some distributions use a different location, such as `/etc/zsh/z*` or `/usr/local/etc/z*`. Check `man zsh` on your system under “Startup/Shutdown Files” or under “Files”.

Normally the system configuration files are installed with zsh, but only contain comments. If you don't find them, this is a sign that you're looking in the wrong place.

On Arch Linux, the [zsh startup files](https://man.archlinux.org/man/zsh.1#STARTUP/SHUTDOWN_FILES) are under `/etc/zsh`.

It's unusual to add aliases to the system startup files. Aliases are typically a personal preference. To get your preferred aliases when you run a root shell, keep the `HOME` environment variable pointing to your home directory. With sudo:

- Run `sudo zsh` and make sure that `HOME` is in the `env_keep` list in `/etc/sudoers`;
- or run `sudo -s` and additionally make sure that `/etc/sudoers` does not set the options `set_home` or `always_set_home`;
- or run `sudo HOME=~ zsh`.

Comment: Thanks. The user of the system is only I. But I tried to apply aliases to all "interactive" logins, because I could use root and some other service accounts (that I use run to run apps with) from time to time, and I wanted to have the same aliases. The reason I log in as the service accounts is mainly to check if file permissions are working.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading wrong documentation. `zsh` does not use `/etc/zshrc` at all.

Here is the official documentation: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html

And some nice tutorial: https://www.zerotohero.dev/zshell-startup-files/

Comment: You're citing an introduction to zsh. It doesn't list all features. Zsh *does* read startup files under `/etc`, as documented in the [reference manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files).